# Error calling SSL payment gateway: "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, ssl, braintree

Making my first steps at implementing payment gateways.

Calling both Braintree and Beantream payment gateways from my ASP.net code behind hosted in IIS 8.5 under win 8.1 results in :

> "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
>   relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel"

**Note that calling the same services from my middle-tier that sits on the same box works fine, so the certificate is installed properly.**

Here's sample code to call the Braintree service thru their SDK:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static CheckinDetailResponse GetViewData()
        {
            CheckinDetailResponse response = new CheckinDetailResponse()
            {
                ClientToken = string.Empty,
                IsSuccessful = false,
                ErrorMessage = string.Empty
            };

            try
            {

                response.ClientToken = GetPaymentToken(); 
                response.IsSuccessful = true;
            }
            catch (BaseDataServicesException ex)
            {
                response.ErrorMessage = ex.GetLocalizedMessage(Resources.WebCommon.ResourceManager);
            }

            return response;

        }


    private static string GetPaymentToken()
            {
                var gateway = new BraintreeGateway
                {
                    Environment = Braintree.Environment.SANDBOX,
                    MerchantId = "999",
                    PublicKey = "999",
                    PrivateKey = "999"
                };


                 var clientToken = gateway.ClientToken.generate(null);
                return JsonDcSerialization.ToJsonString(clientToken); ;
            }
```

Is there some special setting that needs to be done in IIS in order to call SSL services from a web app?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you passing along a client certificate from your web app as part of the service invocation? Show the code for the service invocation.

Comment: @user469104, Added code sample above. Not passing the cert per se, I'm using their SDK's and sample code.

Comment: Some questions. Is their service expecting a client certificate to be passed? I.e. is the service using client certificates for authentication? When you say you are calling the service successfully from your middle-tier, does that middle-tier use the same code/API/SDK as above? If not, what does the middle-tier use?

Comment: @user469104 Don't know what they expect really , but yes the m-t uses the exact same SDK and code as the ASP code-behind and this works fine. So the cert thing seems to be a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the SSL Certificates are installed on the machine, if you do pass them on you code, and also if the machine you're using is configured to accept the certificate issuer as trusted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as you can read in bold in my question, if the m-t installed on the same machine can make the calls, doesn't this prove that the certificate is installed properly? And I did check and the cert is there.

Answer (score 0):

if this is a certificate issued from a third party certification authority you may need to pass the signer certificate (aka intermediate ca) along with the public key (eventually in pkcs#7 format). In the case you're using a self-signed certificate you may need to have the root imported into the mmc trusted root certification authority store.

I tend to think it's the first case as untrusted error message is usually referred to the lack of a piece in the chain of trust.

Hope this help.

Comment: I'm simply using the SDK provided by braintree here, I'm not passing the certificate myself. Anything that needs to be set in IIS maybe? cause the m-t- works...